# Does the Hausdorff-Young inequality hold on bounded sets?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose $1\leq p \leq 2$. The Hausdorff-Young inequality
states that
$$\|\hat{f}\|_{L^{p^{\prime}}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq
\|f\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\quad (1)$$

where $p^{\prime}$ is the conjugate exponent of $p$.

Probably the easiest way to prove (1) is interpolation between the trivial estimate
$$\|\hat{f}\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq
\|f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)},$$
and Plancherel's identity:
$$\|\hat{f}\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq
\|f\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$.

My question is does the inequality (1) hold on bounded sets that contain the origin, i.e., is it true that
$$\|\hat{f}\|_{L^{p^{\prime}}(\Omega)}\leq
\|f\|_{L^{p}(\Omega)},$$
where $\Omega$ is a bounded measurable set with a finite Lebesgue measure such that $0\in \Omega$ ?

Comment: that can't possibly be right; the behavior of $\hat f$ on $\Omega$ is determined by all of $f$, not by just $f|_\Omega$.

Comment: Yes.  But the norm of $f|_{\Omega}$ is controlled by the norm of $f$. And I think I can prove the answer is true in balls. But I am still double-chicking it.

Comment: the fact that the norm of $f|_\Omega$ is controlled by the norm of $f$ gives an inequality in the wrong direction. Let us know when you've proved it for balls...

Comment: I'll give you $10,000 for a correct proof for balls.

Comment: @OliverDiaz ??? That's exactly what the first sentence of the post says...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $n=1$ for simplicity. Let $\Omega=[-1,1]$. Let $f=\chi_{[2,3]}$. Then  $f|_\Omega=0$, but $\hat f$ does not vanish on $\Omega$ (either calculate $\hat f$ explicitly or note that it's analytic, so it can't vanish on $[-1,1]$ without vanishing identically).

Comment: Thank you David